# How can we know what the future will look like?

Tags: futurology

People have always been intrigued of what the future will look like. The answers are quite simple and here we have them for the next 50 years.

To be able to understand the future, we must know the past. What has taken us to where we are today and what has changed along the way.

The world has changed a lot in the last 150 years, but we humans are driven by the same basic needs as we were 150 years ago, food, sleep, sex, the feeling of being appreciated and loved.

**Another question :** Will this change in the next 150 years?

Comment: Inmidate future: if I throw x it will hit the wall, we can do. Predicting a day to the future: The weather tomorrow will be x, 95% accuracy with enough data. Predicting a week to the future: week weather forecast has about 75 - 80% accuracy. Next year economy stock grow or shrink: just slightly over a random guess with 50% - 55%. 5 years in the future economy: within error margin of random guess. Any 5 < X < 50 years in the future: I'll be out of town before you discover I was wasting your time.  Any X >= 50 years, even if scientists are confident, we may not be around! don't bother.

Comment: I guess what you want shouldn't be "what will happen x amount of time from now?" but picking things that are seemingly inevitable and try to assign them a time frame. At least that makes for convincing literature in my opinion.

Comment: @Theraot , Thank you for your effort and time

Answer (score 4):

If we're talking about future in long terms - we never know. We can assume how it will look like though.

And here you are absoulutely correct - we assume by looking at our past(or more likely present) and we exaggerate the tech of the given time.

When we invented first machines, people thought in the far future we'll have something like this [image]

When we invented helicopters, people thought that by 2010 we'll all be using choppers as our primary means of transportation(can't recall the source though).

And now... Well, we basically do the same thing. When we think about our future, we think about huge metal spaceship, laser weapons, mechs and stuff like that.

But what if in, let's say, 10 years somebody invents superior bio-engineering that'll allow us to make living buildings, vehicles, weapons and stuff like that? I think we'll have different views on future then. That is why we can only assume.